# How to build Linux 'script' command from sources

Tags: linux

I've a Linux MIPS tool chain. I want the Linux 'script' command ported to MIPS processor.
Where can I get sources of the 'script' command ? It doesn't seem to be part of core utils or bin utils.

Thanks,
LML

Comment: At the bottom of the man page:  "AVAILABILITY - 
     The script command is part of the util-linux package and is available
     from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/.
"

Comment: Thanks for all quick replies. The man page my system has for script doesn't contain Availability section. I could get the sources from the link given. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
man script
```

...

### Availability

The script command is part of the util-linux package and is available from Linux Kernel Archive ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of [util-linux](http://freecode.com/projects/util-linux), and available [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/). [Here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.24/v2.24-ReleaseNotes) are the most recent Release Notes.

Also [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) includes `script`.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page under `AVAILABILITY`:

> The script command is part of the util-linux package and is available from Linux Kernel Archive ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/.

In fact, the latest version at the time of this answer is in ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.24/util-linux-2.24.tar.gz in the `util-linux-2.24\term-utils\` directory.